# Scrollability without Editability inside a UITextField

Tags: ios, text, scroll

I want to use `UITextFields` for inputting relatively small amounts of text. The text can be longer than the size of the text field, and I want the user to be able to touch/scroll inside the text field in order to be able to read all of it.

This type of semi-scroll-like behavior is available in edit mode, but I don't want the user to be able to edit, just scroll. The keyboard shouldn't come up in other words. (I do allow the user to do editing, but that's in another section of the app.)

I'm suspecting that `UITextField` wasn't built to do what I'm trying to do and that I should go explore the capabilities of `UITextView` instead. Since I've already made a fair investment in providing the infrastructure to support `UITextField` editing (when it's needed, just not in the current circumstances), I'm a bit reluctant to abandon `UITextFields` altogether.

Does anyone see a way of doing what I want to be able to do?

Howard

Answer (score 1):

y dont u use UITextView instead of textfield with small size

Comment: As I've said, I've invested some time and code (tho not a huge amount) in building behaviour based on the UITextField and UITextFieldDelegate APIs. If I abandon UITextField, I'll have to rewrite that code. That doesn't seem as daunting a task now as it did when I first posted on this subject however.

Comment: no problem man u can get more tutorial for UITextView in internet.so dont bother because all of the methods for them also same concept.but with different syntax.see here same . but only small changes u have to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a scroll view with the UILabel as the subview of the scroll view?

Alternatively, use a UITextView and set its editable property to NO. If you are worried about the styling of the textview, use the plain style and customized with other UI elements.

Comment: I tried setting `editable` to NO. That's when I discovered I no longer had scrollability and raised this issue in the first place.

Comment: I said use a UITextView, which does allow scrolling. If you are worried about having to learn new delegate APIs, don't be. As UITextField and UiTextView inherit from the same protocols (UITextInputTraits etc), the APIs are very similar.